# Ng Bootstrap Modal closing on submit button instead of submitting the Angular form in Modal

Tags: angular, forms, modal-dialog

I've created a angular reactive form inside a ng-bootstrap modal. I've a submit button in form to submit the form but instead of submitting the form my modal closes and the page is reloaded.

Comment: Can you share your form code and submit method from ts file.

Comment: NOT use button type="submit" and (submit) event of the form, use in button type="button" and (click) event

Comment: I've used the second method but I thinks its a way around. I'm looking for a proper way.